# Implementing per-user storage usage quota in SaaS products

Tags: architecture, saas

In a SaaS solution, that allows users to maintain their data on the server, if I have to implement various pricing schemes, where each scheme offers different storage quota, say, *Basic* subscription gets you 2GB storage, whereas *Premium* gets you 10GB storage - what kind of architecture one has to use?

1. Do I need to maintain against user profile the quota being used?
2. Will this work only if data is maintained in file system?  What happens if data is stored in relational or NoSQL database - how one keeps track of user-level usage of storage in such cases?